# Angular UI - Modal Height relative to window Height

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a modal with quite a bit of text.  I'm trying to figure out how to restrict the modal height to size of the window and add a scrollbar to the content area, above the OK button.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pzflxb3x35XtIDTkWs2O?p=preview)

```
<note>
          <to>Tove</to>
          <from>Jani</from>
          <to>Tove</to>
          <from>Jani</from>
          <to>Tove</to>
          <from>Jani</from>
          <to>Tove</to>
          <from>Jani</from>
          <to>Tove</to>
          <from>Jani</from>
          <to>Tove</to>
          <from>Jani</from>
          <to>Tove</to>
          <from>Jani</from>
          <to>Tove</to>
          <from>Jani</from>
          <to>Tove</to>
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated to use the window.innerHeight and have an attribute/directive called clientHeight that takes some number and uses it as a percentage to multiply by the window.innerHeight to size some contents and set the overflow-y

http://plnkr.co/edit/9eg3jH0vILntygMn3ieD?p=preview

```
app.directive('clientHeight', function(){
  return {
    link:function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
      debugger;
      iElem.css('height', window.innerHeight*iAttrs.clientHeight/100+'px')
      iElem.css('overflow-y', 'scroll')
    }
  }
});
```

You can probably pull this off with CSS alone maybe using "calc" or otherwise but if not the above JS solution works fine too.

Comment: You might need to wrap this in a function and call it also onWindowResize() browser event.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use CSS, no need for JavaScript.

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: 500px; /* adjust to your needs */
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: I don't want a fixed height.  I want it relative to the user's browsers height.